# Spark, Why does dropping columns cause spark job to fail?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark 2.0, I am running a pyspark job where I read from a table, add some columns whose logic is based off of windowing on 30 days worth of data and then I use `df.createOrReplaceTempView` followed up with `spark.sql(create table as select * from ...)` to create a table in HDFS.

This job runs successfully and creates a table in HDFS. However, I don't need all of the columns I just created in my dataframe. I only need half of the new columns and so I add some logic to drop the columns I don't need (all of these columns that will be dropped were recently created). When I run the drop `df = df.select([c for c in df.columns if c not in  ('a','b','d','e')]) the spark job now fails!

error: `Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 139 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 139.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 405, myhost, executor 197): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 197 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_111 on host: myhost. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: Container killed on request. Exit code is 143`

Answer (score 0):

You can use .drop("colname") to drop the columns from dataframe.

```
df1=df.drop("a","b","c","d")
```

Hope it helps you.